# Alt-Tab tool to switch to a window by typing its name

Tags: windows, software-rec, alt-tab

Is there a task switcher – a replacement for <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> on Windows XP or 7 – that enables switching to a window by typing part of its name?

Answer (score 5):

On Windows version that support Aero, <strike>[Switcher](http://insentient.net/)</strike>  http://web.archive.org/web/20180330150352/http://www.insentient.net/
does what you're looking for. (Outdated, find the last version at https://download.cnet.com/Switcher/3000-12565_4-10665605.html)

In order to enable searching by name, change the following settings:

#### Filters

- Enable **Begin searching by typing**.<sup>1</sup>

#### Shortcuts

- Click **Change**.<sup>2</sup>
- Select the desired keyboard shortcut.<sup>3</sup>
- Set **Activate when shortcut is** to **Released**.<sup>3</sup>
- Disable **End session when shortcut is released**.<sup>3</sup>

Now you can switch to Google Chrome, for example, with the following shortcut sequence:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The end results depend on further settings. With **Dock** view, you get something like this:

[image: result]

---

<sup>1</sup>
[image: filters]

<sup>2</sup>
[image: shortcuts]

<sup>3</sup>
[image: change shortcuts]

Answer (score 4):

In windows 7 you can pin application (you need to pin them to keep the numbers consistent) to the task bar and launch them with win+(1-9) which also works for switching.