# In Windows, is it possible to search Alt-Tab for a specific program?

Tags: windows, windows-10, alt-tab

When using Alt-Tab in Windows 10, is there a way to filter for a particular open program/window by either keyboard input or searching?

I've tried using Win-Tab and then Ctrl-F to search for an open program, but apparently it doesn't search window/program names, only whatever filename was open in that particular program (pretty silly that it doesn't also include program names in this search, IMO).

There used to be a great program that implemented this functionality, [Switcher](https://web.archive.org/web/20160311050757/http://insentient.net/Index.html), but alas, it is no more.

This answer shows how it was able to do this: https://superuser.com/a/443262/122060

Answer (score 0):

If you use Microsoft PowerToys, [PowerToys Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/run) lets you search for open windows by hitting `Ctrl-Space` and then starting your query with `<`. This used to be part of [Window Walker](https://github.com/betsegaw/windowwalker/). I'm not aware of anything natively, though.

Answer (score -1):

[Switcheroo](https://github.com/kvakulo/Switcheroo)

"Switcheroo is for anyone who spends more time using a keyboard than a mouse. Instead of alt-tabbing through a (long) list of open windows, Switcheroo allows you to quickly switch to any window by typing in just a few characters of its title."